# Explain hpack macro operators

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, hpack

Today I was working on conferer library and discovered interesting syntax in hpack package.yaml file reminding me some macro language, but I cannot find anything about that topic - no bugs having words operator/macro in hpack tracker.

in package.yaml:

```
_common/lib: !include ../../utils/package.common.yaml

<<: *everything
```

in package.common.yaml:

```
- &everything
  <<: *misc
  <<: *author
  <<: *legal
  <<: *extensions
  <<: *ghcoptions
  <<: *lib
```

So the included file defines a macro and it is used later.

Comment: This is just [regular YAML syntax](https://blog.daemonl.com/2016/02/yaml.html), nothing to do with `hpack`.

Comment: Thanks @Cubic, I would count this comment as an answer, because I see this a hpack parser bug, not stack custom feature beyond standards or something else.